# How to slice a part of tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to slice [3.0 ,33.0].I have tried to access this slice by following code. I'm not so clear about tf.slice command. I'm not so clear about begin and size mentioned in documentaion about this command. Can someone please make it easy to understand.

```
batch = tf.constant([
  [#First image
    [[0.0,10.0],[1.0,11.0]],
    [[3.0,33.0],[4.0,44.0]]
  ],
  [#Second image
    [[5.0,55.0],[6.0,66.0]],
    [[7.0,77.0],[8.0,88.0]]
  ]
])
slice1 = tf.slice(batch,[0,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0]) 
sess = tf.InteractiveSEssion()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
print slice1.eval()
```

Answer (score 4):

I will explain your code with examples, so I created some cases, but first of all I'll explain you [tf.slice(input, begin, size)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice) parametters:

- `input` is a ref to a Tensor.
- `begin` is the index from the slice begins.
- `size` is the offset of the slice.

So `tf.slice` works selecting from `input` a sub-Tensor that starts at `begin` index and end at `begin + size`, treating `begin` and `size` as index vectors. The example below will clarify this:

```
batch = tf.constant([
        [#First image
            [
                [0.0,10.0],
                [1.0,11.0]
            ],
            [
                [3.0,33.0],
                [4.0,44.0]
            ]
        ],
        [#Second image
            [
                [5.0,55.0],
                [6.0,66.0]
            ],
            [
                [7.0,77.0],
                [8.0,88.0]
            ]
        ]
    ])
slice1 = tf.slice(batch,[0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1]) 
slice2 = tf.slice(batch,[0,1,0,0], [1,1,2,2]) 
slice3 = tf.slice(batch,[1,1,1,0], [1,1,1,2]) 
slice4 = tf.slice(batch,[0,0,0,0], [2,2,2,2]) 
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print("slice1: \n" + str(slice1.eval()) + "\n")
print("slice2: \n" + str(slice2.eval()) + "\n")
print("slice3: \n" + str(slice3.eval()) + "\n")
print("slice4: \n" + str(slice4.eval()) + "\n")
```

The outputs in this case are:

```
slice1: 
[[[[ 0.]]]]

slice2: 
[[[[  3.  33.]
   [  4.  44.]]]]

slice3: 
[[[[  8.  88.]]]]

slice4: 
[[[[  0.  10.]
   [  1.  11.]]

  [[  3.  33.]
   [  4.  44.]]]


 [[[  5.  55.]
   [  6.  66.]]

  [[  7.  77.]
   [  8.  88.]]]]
```

- `slice1` selects the first element of the Tensor because of it begins on `[0,0,0,0]` and picks only one element.
- `slice2` selects the first element of the Tensor because of it begins on `[0,1,0,0]` and picks 1 element in the two first dimensions and 2 in three and four dimensions.
- `slice3` selects the first element of the Tensor because of it begins on `[1,1,1,0]` and picks only 1 element in the three first dimensions and 2 in the last.
- `slice4` selects all the element of the Tensor because of it begins on `[0,0,0,0]` and two elements by dimension, so it covers all the Tensor

Note that de number of dimensions are the same in all slides. If you one to remove dimensions with only one element you can use [tf.squeeze](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze).

Comment: I still can't quite get how does tf.slice works, anyone mind to explain on what does [0,0,0,0] and [1,1,1,1] represents in slice1 = tf.slice(batch,[0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1])? is it the index?why does it have 4 values?

Answer (score 0):

As how to slice a tensor is well explained above, I will show the trick about how to slice every element in the same position as `[3.0, 33.0]` in the tensor here (which is a similar problem that I met)

```py
batch = tf.constant([
  [#First image
    [[0.0,10.0],[1.0,11.0]],
    [[3.0,33.0],[4.0,44.0]]
  ],
  [#Second image
    [[5.0,55.0],[6.0,66.0]],
    [[7.0,77.0],[8.0,88.0]]
  ]
])
batch_shape = batch.shape
batch_sliced = tf.slice(batch,(0,1,0,0),(batch_shape[0],1,1,batch_shape[-1]))
```

Then you will get `batch_sliced` as

````
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 1, 1, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[ 3., 33.]]],
       [[[ 7., 77.]]]]```
````